# extract element from xml string

Tags: java, xml, extract

```
<media:thumbnail url="http:// mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/mes1-300x186.png" width="320" length="125399" type="image/jpg"/>
```

How to extract the URL from this xml ? If I have the above as string ?

Comment: Look here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Comment: Hava a look at here
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16712849/1051509

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you have the XML string stored in String str, one lazy and simple way to retrieve the URL (if you always expect the same input text format) could be:

```
String url = str.split("\"")[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Some times, as a quick "one time solution" you can use regular expressions.

```
String xml="<media:thumbnail url=\"http:// mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/    mes1-300x186.png\" width=\"320\" length=\"125399\" type=\"image/jpg\"/>";
Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("url\\s*=\\s*\\\"(.*?)\\\"");
Matcher m=pattern.matcher(xml);
if(m.find()){
   String urlValue=m.group(1);
   System.out.println(urlValue);
}
```