# Simple XML to Java variables

Tags: java, xml, variables, xml-parsing

I am just wondering if there is a simple method to load Java variables (only String) from a XML file, that is like the following. Most of the libraries and methods i read seem to be quite confusing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<registerData>
  <firstname>Max</firstname>
  <lastname>Mustermann</lastname>
  <email>max@mustermann.com</email>
  <company>Max's Mustermänner</company>
</registerData>
```

Thank you for your help!

Benjamin

Comment: What libraries you tried?

Comment: Mention which library you are using? Refer - [HowToAsk](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is way too broad. Pick one of the "confusing" methods, and try to make it work. Chances are, it would work right away. Otherwise, come back and post a more specific question. Good luck!

Comment: here's an example using xpath http://stackoverflow.com/a/21266808/217324 . this way doesn't take a lot of code, it's declarative, and has no configuration overhead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JAXB with annotations.

From memory:

```
@XmlRootElement("registerData")
public class RegisterData {

    @XmlAttribute
    public String firstName;
    ...
}
```

See http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JAXB/article.html - marshal = save, unmarshall = load XML.