# XPath code creates IOException

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have a text document in which each line is an entire US patent XML document. I am trying to parse it to remove certain features like the patent number, etc. I haven't used XPath before, so I'm borrowing some code I found from Ravi Thapliyal
at [Parse XML Simple String using Java XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712391/parse-xml-simple-string-using-java-xpath). However, apparently the initial !DOCTYPE tag is causing the DocumentBuilder to try to find the actual document somewhere?

Here is my first attempt at code:

```
//convert entire file to ArrayList of strings
        ArrayList<String> doc = new ArrayList<>();
        while(input.hasNext()){
            doc.add(input.nextLine().trim());
        }

int index = 0;
    while(index < doc.size()){
        String xml = doc.get(index);
        XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xPath = xpathFactory.newXPath();
        InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));

        db.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver() {
            public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId)
             throws SAXException, java.io.IOException {
                if (systemId.contains("us-patent-grant-v40-2004-12-02.dtd")) {
            return new InputSource(new StringReader(""));
        } else {
            return null;
        }
            }
        });

        String orgName = "";
        try {
            orgName = (String) xPath.evaluate("/agents/adressbook/orgname", source,XPathConstants.STRING);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Document #" + index + " Company: " + orgName);
    }//end while loop that goes through each line (patent document) in file
```

The beginning of each line in the input file contains the following after the DOCTYPE declaration:
us-patent-grant SYSTEM "us-patent-grant-v40-2004-12-02.dtd" [ ]>

The line that causes the problem (91) is:

```
orgName = (String) xPath.evaluate("/agents/adressbook/orgname", 
       source,XPathConstants.STRING);
```

And the stacktrace is:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Dave\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ParseXML\us-patent-grant-v40-2004-12-02.dtd (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:131)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:87)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:616)
Document #0 Company: 
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1293)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1260)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:263)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1164)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1050)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:938)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:466)
    at Parser.main(Parser.java:102)
--------------- linked to ------------------
javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Dave\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ParseXML\us-patent-grant-v40-2004-12-02.dtd (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:473)
    at Parser.main(Parser.java:102)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Dave\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ParseXML\us-patent-grant-v40-2004-12-02.dtd (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:131)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:87)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:616)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1293)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1260)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:263)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1164)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1050)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:938)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:466)
```

Can someone help me figure out what I should be doing to parse a document in a string?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting features or supply empty EntityResolver

For features you need to find what parser implementation do you use (they are implementation specific)

[Make DocumentBuilder.parse ignore DTD references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155101/make-documentbuilder-parse-ignore-dtd-references)

Comment: I've tried that and still get the same error. I've altered the original question to show the new code and the stacktrace as requested. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried builder.setEntityResolver code from link?

Comment: Yes, I just tried that and am getting the exact same stack trace.

Comment: Okay, put in the stack trace and code using setEntityResolver. I'm running out of time, so I might have to try another approach entirely. Thanks, guys.

Comment: try "http://xml.org/sax/features/use-entity-resolver2"=false
and setEntityResolver

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90703/discussion-between-vovka-and-david-farthing).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried supplying the DTD file it's trying to reference, e.g. download it from [us-patent-application-v40-2004-12-02.dtd](https://code.google.com/p/patiprototype/source/browse/trunk/resources/transformation/v40/us-patent-application-v40-2004-12-02.dtd?r=91)?

You can try putting this file in the same folder as the XML; or in the current directory of the parsing process (try both since you're in a hurry).